# Laravel eloquent Join on full table

Tags: join, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to define and retrieve a relationship

**In my User.php model**

```
 public function getClient() {
     return $this->hasOne('\App\Client',  'id');
   }
```

In my client model

```
  public function contact() {
     return $this->hasOne('\App\User',  'client');
   }
```

The **id** of the clients table joins **client** table with the users table.

I try and retrieve with

```
    $all = \App\User::with('getClient')->get();
    return view('users.all')->with('all', $all);
```

but I do not get the results of the join only the original table.

What am I going wrong?

Comment: There a problem in the reverse relationship `public function contact() {
     return $this->belongsTo('\App\User');
}` !!

Comment: For more ditails [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) One To One section :)